# Paging with rowcommand

Tags: c#, gridview, paging, rowcommand

I have a gridview with "select" row and paging. 
I´m getting an error when I try to change paging site.

[image: Here's the image of the problem]

I can get rid of this issue if i use `If()` statement but then my select event wont work.

```
/*************Acitivate "Search" column for every row in gridview******************/
    protected void gwActivity_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        /*if (e.CommandName.ToString() == "Select")*/

        {
            GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)(((LinkButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);           
            txtActivity.Text = row.Cells[2].Text;
            ddlStatus.SelectedValue = row.Cells[4].Text;
            ddlResponsible.SelectedValue = row.Cells[5].Text;
            ddlCategory.SelectedValue = row.Cells[6].Text;
            ddlPriority.SelectedValue = row.Cells[7].Text;
            ddlSize.SelectedValue = row.Cells[8].Text;
            ddlSystem.SelectedValue = row.Cells[9].Text;
            ddlChange_Requestor.SelectedValue = row.Cells[10].Text;
            txtComment.Text = row.Cells[11].Text;


        }

    }
```

**ERROR:**

> *An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in App_Web_rsb5hpia.dll but was not handled in user code
>   Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView' to type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.LinkButton'.*

Answer (score 0):

Try it changing `LinkButton` to `Control`:

```
GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)(((Control)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer);
```

Or use this:

```
GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)((Control)e.CommandSource).Parent.Parent;
```

Or this one:

```
GridViewRow row = ((e.CommandSource as Control).NamingContainer as GridViewRow);
```

Comment: Hi, the last one looks like it works not 100% sure because an error comes on row: txtActivity.Text = row.Cells[2].Text;
ERROR:Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void GridView1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
    {
        int id = int.Parse(((Label)gvListadoActividades.Rows[e.RowIndex].FindControl("MyId")).Text);
        this.DeletedMyid(id);
        this.GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
        this.LoadMyData();
    }
```